# Unable to start bitcoind

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, full-node

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Anyone know why I am getting the following error message?

[image]

---

Other possible relevant info:

Config file location

```
/home/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

---

Config file content:

```
server=1
testnet=0
txindex=1
rpcuser=[username redacted]
rpcpassword=[password redacted]
```

---

bitcoind location:

```
/home/bitcoin-0.19.1/bin/bitcoind
```

---

OS:

Ubuntu 18.04 (fully uptodate)

---

bitcoin-core download location:

```
sudo wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.19.1/bitcoin-0.19.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
```

---

login username:

```
bitcoin
```

---

folder/file permissions (recursive) for bitcoind and bitcoin.conf:

```
777
```

---

After a few seconds, bitcoind automatically stops without warning and allows me to start it again, only to automatically stop again.  How do I figure out why it is not starting, or why it stops after a second or 2?  When it stops, it does not show any error messages in the terminal.  I only know something is wrong if I run a bitcoin-cli command, as seen in the screenshot above.

---

**UPDATE ONE:**

`./bitcoind` output below:

[image]

Comment: Run bitcoind without --daemon and check for error messages

Comment: @pinhead, added output by running `bitcoind` without `-daemon`.  Any idea why that error message is being generated?

Comment: could it be a weird time/date in your output CBlockFileInfo(.... time=01-01-1970.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having all sorts of problems with this.  Decided to copy everything from an NTFS drive to a Ext4 drive.  All problems gone...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your blockchain is corrupted or you have multiple bitcoind processes running. Kill the bitcoind process, go to `/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin` and delete the blocks, chainstate and database directories using

```
rm -r blocks
rm -r chainstate
rm -r database
```

then start the daemon again without the '-daemon' flag to see if it progresses further.